# How to test Google Purchase dialog using automation?

Tags: java, android, gradle, appium, android-espresso

we have a paid app with different SKU combinations.
I tried Appium initially with APK signed with release signature. But Appium  re-sign the APK with Debug Key, which throws error during Google Purchase dialog.

Now I am exploring Espresso, but when I sign the ***-dev-unsigned.APK with Release signature Job and try to run the  automation, it throws the following error -

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting instrumentation ComponentInfo{com.xxx.yyy.test/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner} from pid=25003, uid=25003 not allowed because package com.xxx.yyy.test does not have a signature matching the target com.xxx.yyy.mobile
```

How do I sign test package also with same signature? Where can I find test APK?
I am using Gradle build system.

Answer (score 1):

Using appium,we can do it with `noSign=true` capability flag.